# fullpage site: navigating through elements onclick with each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, click, each

I'm working on a fullpage site and I made a navigation bar but it isn't functional yet. The buttons should take you to the next or previous scene, the first one should bring you to the last scene and the last one to the first scene. Eventually, scrolling would be completely disabled and the only navigation would be those two buttons (prev and next), but I commented that out for now.

I found something on w3schools which I commented out in the last onclick function. I can't seem to make that work.. some help would be very much appreciated!

[I made a codepen.](https://codepen.io/zane3353/pen/MWjEbbV)

```
$(".menu").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).each(function (index) {
    console.log(index);

    if (this.hash !== "") {

      var hash = this.hash;


      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function () {

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;

      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try distinguishing the "Prev" and "Next" buttons by adding additional classes:

```
<a href="#" id="nav1" class="menu prev">Prev</a>
<a href="#" id="nav2" class="menu next">Next</a>
```

and then try the following logic using the modulo operator:

```
  if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
    var hash = "#scene-" + ((curr++ % sections) + 1);
  } else {
    curr = curr == 1 ? (sections + 1) : curr;
    var hash = "#scene-" + (curr-- -1);
  }

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 800, function () {
    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
 });
```

Full working example:

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function () {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).on('resize scroll', function () {

  $('.scenes').each(function () {
    var activeColor = $(this).attr('id');

    if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
      $('#fixed-' + activeColor).addClass(activeColor + '-active');
    } else {
      $('#fixed-' + activeColor).removeClass(activeColor + '-active');
    }

    var page = $("body");
    var page_height = page.height();
    var colorHere = page_height * 0.5;

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > (page_height - colorHere)) {
      $("a").css("color", "white");
    } else {
      $("a").css("color", "black");
    }
  });
});

var sections = 6;
var curr = 1;

$(".menu").on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).each(function (index) {

      if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
        var hash = "#scene-" + ((curr++ % sections) + 1);
      } else {
        curr = curr == 1 ? (sections + 1) : curr;
        var hash = "#scene-" + (curr-- -1);
      }

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function () {
        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
     });
  });
});
```

```css
.scenes{
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

#scene-1{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#scene-2{
    background-color: #ebd5d5;
}

#scene-3{
    background-color: #ea8a8a;
}

#scene-4{
    background-color: #685454;
}

#scene-5{
    background-color: #af6b58;
}

#scene-6{
    background-color: #cbbcb1;
}

/* navigatie */
.menu{
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
}
  

#nav1{
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
   left:45%;
}

#nav2{
    position: fixed;
    top:90%;
    left:45%;
 }




html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scene-1" class="scenes">
  <h2 id="fixed-scene-1">1</h2>
</div>
<div id="scene-2" class="scenes">
  <h2 id="fixed-scene-2">2</h2>
</div>
<div id="scene-3" class="scenes">
  <h2 id="fixed-scene-3">3</h2>
</div>
<div id="scene-4" class="scenes">
  <h2 id="fixed-scene-4">4</h2>
</div>
<div id="scene-5" class="scenes">
  <h2 id="fixed-scene-5">5</h2>
</div>
<div id="scene-6" class="scenes">
  <h2 id="fixed-scene-6">6</h2>
</div>

<a href="#" id="nav1" class="menu prev">Prev</a>
<a href="#" id="nav2" class="menu next">Next</a>
```